# How do I invert a dynamic matrix in Eigen?

Tags: eigen

As far as I can tell, Eigen won't compile if I try to invert a matrix that isn't square. Since the matrix I want to invert is dynamically sized, it doesn't know that both dimensions will be the same, so it won't let me compile it. Is there a way out of this?

Comment: Please give a precise example because calling .inverse() on a MatrixXd object is perfectly fine.

Comment: I looked into it more. Apparently, my problem was that I included Eigen/Core, but not Eigen/LU.

Comment: @DanielLC: it's fine to answer your own question with your findings (and accept that answer). Actually, I encourage you to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invert is in < Eigen/LU >. I was just using < Eigen/Core >. Alternately, I think < Eigen/Dense > loads the whole library, and would have worked.